# Upper star (Mandatory field) for UILabel

Tags: ios, unicode, uilabel

In some form filling application I saw the the upper right star image for mandatory fields.Is it possible to add an upper star to UILabel without using an additional UIImage by using any unicode ??

Comment: Sure. Have you looked for an appropriate Unicode character?

Comment: What about a plain old asterisk? Example: `required*`.

Comment: I didn't get the unicode for that

Comment: Why don't you use simple * appended by your label text?